# jquery datepicker IE 8 second date is not transmitted

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, split, datepicker, undefined

I have a strange problem with the jquery datepicker and IE8. I have 2 datefields in a form using jquery datepicker. Clicking the first field and choosing a date will autofill the second datefield with the choosen date of datefield1 + one day - Everything is working fine in FF, Chrome and the latest IE. But using IE8 the second datefield is filled but not transmitted.

Here is my code:

```
$("#datePick1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    constrainInput: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: false,
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(date) {
        var date2 = $('#datePick1').datepicker('getDate');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
        $('#datePick2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
        $('#datePick2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        var dateParts = date.split(".");
        $('#start_d').val(dateParts[0]);
        $('#start_m').val(dateParts[1]);
        $('#start_y').val(dateParts[2]);

        if ($('#datePick1').val() != '' && $(this).is('#datePick1'))
        {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#datePick2').datepicker('show');
            }, 1);
        }
    }
}).on('focus', function() {
    $(this).trigger('blur');
});

$('#datePick2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: false,
    onClose: function(date2) {
        var datePick1 = $('#datePick1').datepicker('getDate');
        console.log(datePick1);
        var datePick2 = $('#datePick2').datepicker('getDate');
        if (datePick2 <= datePick1) {
            var minDate = $('#datePick2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
            $('#datePick2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
        }
        var dateParts = date2.split(".");
        $('#end_d').val(dateParts[0]);
        $('#end_m').val(dateParts[1]);
        $('#end_y').val(dateParts[2]);
    }
}).on('focus', function() {
    $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

Using the IE8 debugger is telling me `var dateParts = date2.split(".");` is undefined (see second block).

Any ideas?